# Django DRF & Updating multiple partial records

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-serializer

I'm attempting to update a model that has more fields than what I want to pass to it.  I've read the DRF documentation and I'm not finding the right approach.  I came across using the UpdateModelMixin but I cannot seem to find a way to implement it successfully.

I've taken a few approaches so far, including using APIView in addition to the methods seen below.

Ultimately, I wish to pass the following to my view and have it update just the "order" field in my model.  My model has many fields.

```
[
    {
        "id": "1",
        "order": "5"
    },
    {
        "id": "2",
        "order": "3"
    }
]
```

This is my view:

```
class WaitlistListGen(generics.ListCreateAPIView):
    queryset = Waitlist.objects.all()
    serializer_class = WaitlistSerializer


class WaitlistDetailGen(RetrieveUpdateDestroyAPIView):
    queryset = Waitlist.objects.all()
    serializer_class = WaitlistSerializer
```

And, this is my serializer:

```
class WaitlistSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
        model = Waitlist
        fields = '__all__'
```

Answer (score 0):

I finally figured it out and believe this is the best approach--I'll take feedback if it's not.  I had to create a new view, extend the put method, and iterate over the data.  I used the existing WaitlistSerializer:

```
class WaitlistUpdateGen(generics.UpdateAPIView):
    serializer_class = WaitlistSerializer

    def put(self, request):
        waitlist_data = request.data
        for waitlist_item in waitlist_data:
            try:
                waitlist = Waitlist.objects.get(id=waitlist_item['id'])
            except Waitlist.DoesNotExist:
                return Response(status=status.HTTP_404_NOT_FOUND)

            serializer = self.serializer_class(
                waitlist, data=waitlist_item, partial=True)
            if serializer.is_valid():
                serializer.save()

        return Response(status=status.HTTP_200_OK)
```